# Why is the comma messing up the insert

Tags: sql, mysql

here is my query

```
insert into invoices 
  set Invoice_number = '823N9823',
      price = '11,768.00',
      code = 'ret_4_business', 
      created_at = '2010-09-27';
```

but my price in my db is 11, not 11768

how do i handle money in mysql? the field is a decimal

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Invoice_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`price` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: `DECIMAL(10.0)` should just as well be `INT`, because it won't capture the cents unless you specify more than zero digits.  Like `DECIMAL(10.2)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any non-number character will terminate the parsing and save only part of the number. Remove the comma characters from the query.